# Why can't I use normal Views with an ApiController?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, asp.net-web-api

Why can't I create a view directly from an `ApiController`?

Both `Controller` and `ApiController` just receive and supply data, why can't my `ApiController` just output and recieve data formatted for and from a View?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, [`actually it can`](http://weblogs.asp.net/fredriknormen/archive/2012/07/17/asp-net-web-api-and-using-razor-the-next-step.aspx). You could use the [`RazorViewEngine`](http://razorengine.codeplex.com/) to build a custom media type formatter which will pass the model to a Razor view.

Unfortunately Microsoft did a pretty lousy job of making Web Api controllers having to derive from a different base class than standard MVC controllers. Hopefully in future versions they will fix this design.

As an alternative you may take a look at [`ServcieStack`](http://www.servicestack.net/) which provide you with a real nice interface to build RESTful API which can render any type of resource including HTML views from a single service.